# How do I create my first database for .NET development?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, sql-server-2005

Ok!  I'm ready to embark on some .NET development for the first time.

I've recently installed Microsoft Visual Studio which included Microsoft SQL Sever 2005.

What is the prefered method for programming against a development database?  I want to write an ASP.NET application that uses a database and I'm not sure how to create one.  In my start menu for SQL Server 2005 all I have is:

- SQL Server Configuration Manager
- SQL Server Error and Usage Reports
- SQL Server Surface Area Config

I don't see an intuitive program to create and design databases on that list, so how do I do it?!  Will I be creating a full fledged SQL Server database or a "flat-file" fake database to program against?

Can someone please tell me what is up on creating my first MS SQL Server 2005 database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've Visual Studio, just goto server explorer, Add a new database connection to your database, and start off.

Or, create a new website project in Visual studio, right click the App_Data folder->Add New Item and add a SQL Server database mdf file, which will be attached to the sql server when you run the app. You need to deploy the mdf file when doing a production release :)

You might want to watch the videos in ASP.NET website http://www.asp.net/learn/

Otherwise, consider using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (an express edition is also available).

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en). Its pretty easy to add a database once you get your head around it.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, the SQL Server included with Visual Studio is an express edition. However, the one thing it is lacking is the SQL Server Management Studio (Express). I'd download and install the [express edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/2005/sql/register/) that included the management studio (note that VS 2005 and 2008 include SQL Express 2005, you can use either SQL Express 2005 or 2008 for your purposes).

You can create a new database and do everything you need to from within the VS IDE but you'll probably find the SQL Management Studio environment much more intuitive and simpler to use as a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

A quick note on SQL Express - Microsoft doesn't suggest it for 'production' environments due to limitations placed on the amount of RAM that Express can see/use and a few other factors.  This is one of the few cases in which I agree - if you're doing anything complex that involves large databases or dozens of users then invest in MSSQL Workgroup Edition at least, or for Enterprise projects use MSSQL Standard or Enterprise versions.